# Groovy :: Map Find Recursive

Tags: recursion, groovy, dictionary, find

**Edit**
See @tim's solution below for the "correct" Groovy-esque approach to map recursion.  Since Map findRecursive does not yet exist in Groovy, if you find yourself needing this functionality in various parts of your app, just add it to Map metaClass:

```
Map.metaClass.findRecursive = {String key->
    if(delegate.containsKey(key)) return delegate."$key"
    else
        for(m in delegate) {
            if(m.value in Map) return m.value.findRecursive(key)
        }
}
// then anywhere in your app
someMap.findRecursive('foo')
```

**Original**
Was hoping something like findResult{it.key=='foo'} would recurse through map elements beyond 1-d deep, but appears not to be the case.

Rolled my own recursive map finder, but am wondering if there's a better way to do this.  Maybe there's a built-in function I'm missing, or an even Groovier (concise) way to pull off the below:

```
Map map = [school:[id:'schoolID', table:'_school',
    children:[team:[id:'teamID',table:'_team',
        children:[player:[id:'playerID',table:'_roster']]
    ]]
]]

class Foo {
    static finder = {Map map, String key->
        if(map.containsKey(key)) return map[key]
        else
            for(m in map) {
                if(m.value in Map) return this.finder(m.value,key)
            }
    }
}
println Foo.finder(map,'team')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Groovy 1.8 (reqd for the findResult method), you could do something like this:

```
class DeepFinder {
  static Object findDeep( Map map, Object key ) {
    map.get( key ) ?: map.findResult { k, v -> if( v in Map ) v.findDeep( key ) }
  }
}

use( DeepFinder ) {
  println map.findDeep( 'team' )
}
```

There's no recursing default Groovy method that I know of...

Comment: +1 @tim, nice alternative solution. (Map)m.findRecursive('foo') would be a nice addition to Groovy.lang, imo.

Comment: @virtual, I agree...  Maybe come up with a patch for DGM, a couple of tests, and submit them to the JIRA?  Might make it into 1.8.2

Comment: right, may post this on Groovy user first, could be a reason why this has not yet been implemented.  In meantime, edited my post to add recursive finder to Map metaClass (coming from dreadful LAMP stack, it is truly amazing to have your cake and eat it too ;--))