# Recursively extracting JSON field values in Groovy

Tags: recursion, groovy, jsonslurper

I need to implement a method that will scan a string of JSON for a particular `targetField` and either return the value of that field (if it exists), or `null` (if it doesn't):

```
// Ex: extractFieldValue(/{ "fizz" : "buzz" }/, 'fizz') => 'buzz'
// Ex: extractFieldValue(/{ "fizz" : "buzz" }/, 'foo') => null
String extractFieldValue(String json, String targetField) {
    // ...
}
```

This solution has to be recursive and work at any nesting-level in the (hierarchical) JSON string. Also it needs to work for JSON arrays as well.

My best attempt so far:

```
String extractFieldValue(String json, String targetField) {
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def jsonMap = slurper.parseText(json)

    jsonMap."${targetField}"
}
```

This only works on top-level (non-nested) JSON fields. I asked the Google Gods how to use `JsonSlurper` recursively, but couldn't find anything useful. Any ideas here?

Comment: what if multiple match?

Comment: Pretty sure when you've slurped the JSON into a map, you can use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185746/groovy-map-find-recursive

Comment: Good point @tim_yates - I'd be happy with taking the first value found.

Comment: Or something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748965/how-to-search-value-by-key-from-map-as-well-as-nested-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this input string in a variable called `json`:

```
{
    "a":"a",
    "b":{"f":"f", "g":"g"},
    "c":"c",
    "d":"d",
    "e":[{"h":"h"}, {"i":{"j":"j"}}],
}
```

This script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def mapOrCollection (def it) {
    it instanceof Map || it instanceof Collection
}

def findDeep(def tree, String key) {
    switch (tree) {
        case Map: return tree.findResult { k, v ->
            mapOrCollection(v)
                ? findDeep(v, key)
                : k == key
                    ? v
                    : null
        }
        case Collection: return tree.findResult { e ->
            mapOrCollection(e)
                ? findDeep(e, key)
                : null
        }
        default: return null
    }
}

('a'..'k').each { key ->
    def found = findDeep(new JsonSlurper().parseText(json), key)
    println "${key}: ${found}"
}
```

Gives these results:

```
a: a
b: null
c: c
d: d
e: null
f: f
g: g
h: h
i: null
j: j
k: null
```